# Java code to check for JVM options

Tags: java, jvm

Can any one help me with some referenes as to how I can check different values passed to the JVM. For example if I invoke the jvm with the following options "`-Djava.library.path=lib`", how do I check what is passed as library arguments to the JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The things set by the `-D` flag are called sytem properties. You can retrieve them using [`System.getProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)). eg:

```
System.getProperty("java.library.path")
```

There are a few other methods in `System` that may be of interest you you, like `System.getProperties` which returns the entire set of system properties.

Note that there are some system properties that will have values even without being set by the `-D` flag.